# How to use API interface class if we have thousnds of API call in Android using Retrofit?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

While using Retrofit to make API call in Android we have to create an API service class that may look like some below

```
@POST("endpoint")
Call<ModelClass> getUserDetail(@Body HashMap<String, Object> user_id);
```

Now if my app is on large scale and there may be thousands of APIs to declare.

How to deal with such scenarios is it mandatory to write all the calls likewise as given above?

Please let me know if there is any alternative solution for this.

Comment: Just Keep different endpoints in different interfaces one example would be  1) say you are authenticating user interface would be `AuthenticatorService` and  2) say you are uploading documents to server interface would be `UploadService`

Comment: Yes we can do like that but we are also creating same number of functions in that also